# WYMeditor inserting a <br /> when empty

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0, wymeditor

I'm using WYMeditor for this project. However, I have server side validation that checks that a textarea box is non-empty before it saves the data. But when using WYMeditor, it is inserting a `<br />` tag even though I haven't even done so much as click inside the editor.

I searched around regarding this problem and found that it was labelled as a bug, [here](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/issues/193%22here%22). But it was said to be fixed. However it's definitely still affecting me, even though I have downloaded and am using the latest stable version.

This is my code for inserting the textarea (I'm using CakePHP):

```
echo $this->Form->create('News', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('News.title', array('label' => '*Title:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('News.body', array('label' => '*Body:', 'class' => 'wymeditor'));
    echo $this->Form->input('News.picture', array('label' => 'Picture:', 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Save News', 'class' => 'wymupdate'));
```

And my javascript for the textarea:

```
jQuery('.wymeditor').wymeditor({
            skin: 'silver',
            toolsItems: [
                         {'name': 'Bold', 'title': 'Strong', 'css': 'wym_tools_strong'}, 
                         {'name': 'Italic', 'title': 'Emphasis', 'css': 'wym_tools_emphasis'},
                         {'name': 'CreateLink', 'title': 'Link', 'css': 'wym_tools_link'},
                         {'name': 'Unlink', 'title': 'Unlink', 'css': 'wym_tools_unlink'},
                         {'name': 'InsertOrderedList', 'title': 'Ordered_List', 'css': 'wym_tools_ordered_list'},
                         {'name': 'InsertUnorderedList', 'title': 'Unordered_List', 'css': 'wym_tools_unordered_list'},
                         {'name': 'InsertTable', 'title': 'Table', 'css': 'wym_tools_table'},
                         {'name': 'Undo', 'title': 'Undo', 'css': 'wym_tools_undo'},
                         {'name': 'Redo', 'title': 'Redo', 'css': 'wym_tools_redo'}
                        ]
        });
```

I have tested this not using the wymeditor javascript, but all my other javascript, and it functions as expected, so I suspect something is going on with the wymeditor javascript, but I'm unsure as to what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possible reasons for these symptoms:

1. You could be using an old version of WYMeditor where this bug was present. Which version are you using? As of this writing, the current version is [1.0.0b3](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/version.txt). You can test against WYMeditor master [here](http://wymeditor.no.de/wymeditor/examples/01-basic.html).
2. If you're submitting the form without using the form's submit handler, then the `wymupdate` class won't work, and you won't get the implicit `wym.xhtml()` call, which means that some necessary HTML cleanup might not occur. You could try calling `xhtml()` on your WYMeditor instance (you can retrieve it with `jQuery.wymeditors(0)` if you only have one wymeditor).

If you can provide an example page, or a bit more info, I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: 1 was the solution for me. Silly me, picked what they called the latest "stable" version. I like stability, but I prefer working. Thanks.